# Is it possible to continuously read a database in python?

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi

I am developing a 3D Scanner using a Raspberry Pi and a Canon SLR. To control the reflex and the turntable, I use a simple web interface that I developed.

But I have to make the link between a "Start" or "Pause" buttons between the HTML interface and the Python control program. So I create a database to store the settings for the SLR (ISO, Shutterspeed ...).

For example, is it possible to have a box in the database with a state `true` or `false` for the pause button and then read it continuously on the python program?

I made a little test code like this below :

```
import mysql.connector
import time 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="scanner",
    passwd="valentin",
    database="Scanner3D"
    )

print(mydb)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT a FROM test")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()    
print(myresult)
myresult = str(myresult)
print(myresult)
x = myresult[2:4]
print(x)

while x == "10":

    print("Hello World")
    time.sleep(1)

    mycursor.execute("SELECT a FROM test")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    myresult = str(myresult)
    x = myresult[2:4]
    print(x)
```

Problem is when I change the value of A in the database, the program never displays the new value and never leaves the loop, what is wrong in here?

Comment: You should use some [inter-process communication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) like a socket to send a message in real-time.

Comment: How do you determine that the value has changed in the DB? Maybe you forgot to ``commit`` it?

Comment: @KlausD yeah maybe but I have never used this method yet.

Comment: @MikeScotty Normally the commit is used only when writing in the database? No ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking if the "sender" did a proper commit, otherwise your process will not see that the value has changed. Since the code you posted does not contain an UPDATE statement, it must happen elsewhere, and magic crystal balls have yet to be invented ;)

Comment: @MikeScotty Unfortunately, the crystal balls do not exist yet ... But I did the update by hand using PhpmyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use real-time communication like websocket.
The simplest way is: When scanner scans some value and saves it to DB, send via websocket command to client, to pull new data from server. Or you can send new data right in websocket message.

Very nice tutorial is here: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/